# (L)BNF grammar for GAMS

Tags: system, grammar, modeling, bnf, gams-math

Is there a place I can find Backus–Naur Form (BNF) grammar for General Algebraic Modeling System (GAMS)? I have searched the web but have turned up empty handed. I figure it must exist somewhere.

Comment: I have not seen any grammar described for GAMS and I suspect that a formal description has never been elucidated. However, I must ask, what would you do with such a thing.

Comment: I am writing my master's thesis around it and I could do more around the analysis of GAMS programs if I didn't have to write the lexer/parser by myself first.